# Find an ortho-normal basis of a given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is from last year question paper and I am confused about the question. It states:-

find an orthonormal basis for a subspace : $$W = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{C}^4 : x_1 +ix_2 =0,\; x_2+x_3-x_4 = 0 \}$$

I came up with the solution:-
$x_1 + ix_2 = 0 \implies x_1=x_2=0$
Also since $x_2=0, x_2+x_3-x_4 = 0 \implies x_3=x_4$

Thus $$W = \{\alpha(0,0,1,1): \alpha \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
however now $W$ has dimension equal to $1$ and thus no other orthonormal basis exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: $x_1+ix_2=0$ does not imply that $x_1=x_2=0$. Consider $x_1=1, x_2=i$

Answer (score 1):

Using the equations satisfied by the vectors in $W$, you can conclude that:$$W = \{(-i\alpha, \alpha, \beta, \alpha+\beta): \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}\}$$

This easily gives you a basis for $W$. Namely $v_1 = (-i,1,0,1)$ and $v_2 = (0,0,1,1)$. However, $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is not an orthonormal basis. All you have to do is use the [Gram-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) procedure to orthonormalize it.

You should get $e_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}(-i,1,0,1)$ and $e_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}(i,-1,3,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace $W$ is the kernel of the linear map $f\colon\mathbb{C}^4\to\mathbb{C}^2$ induced by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The reduced row echelon form is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -i & i \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so a basis of the kernel is
$$
\left\{\,
\begin{bmatrix} i \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -i \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\,\right\}
$$
A simple Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization will give the required orthogonal basis.